# Grabbing functions from dlls using GetProc and stepping into them?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging, dll, stack

I have the following code:

```
  GetNumberOfFormatsFunc getNumberOfFormats = (GetNumberOfFormatsFunc)lib.GetProc("GetNumberOfFormats");
  if (getNumberOfFormats != NULL)
  {
    RINOK(getNumberOfFormats(&numFormats));
  }
```

The function GetProc does this:

```
GetProcAddress(module, proceName)
```

when the function 'getNumberOfFormats' is called the debugger does not step into it, even if I press 'F11' on it. It also doesn't tell me I missed a callstack.

The function exists in a separate project and it links to that projects copmiled DLL. Any ideas why I can't step into the code?

Comment: Even if you can't step into it, does the function get called properly?

Comment: Function gets called no problem, whatever is supposed to execute in it does execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio can't find debug symbols for your DLL. Check whether PDB file is generated for your DLL and exists.

Comment: Actually i just found there was a 7z.pdb in the debug directory which would correspond to 7z.dll that it's linkin into from there...

Comment: nevermind the last comment, the pdb was generated but it was in the debug directory of a different folder to the debug folder of the project actually loading the lib. Moving the pdb to the same folder as the debug directory of the project which was loading the 7z dll fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the symbol loaded information while debugging from Debug->Windows->Modules. Right click on the desired DLL and configure the proper symbol if not properly loaded.